# How to create array of the certain type in python

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

How do you create an array of defined length of the certain type in python? To be precise I am trying to create an array of handles that is able to hold up to 1024 records. I figured out an analog to HANDLE type in python, which would be **c_void_p** of **ctypes**.

For example C++ code would have:

```
HANDLE myHandles[1024];
```

What would be python analogy to the C++ code above?
Thank you for your input.

Comment: I would read here.. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, you generally just create an array, and you can put any values you like in it.  It's dynamic.

```
my_handles = []
```

You can put as many of any type of values in this as you want now.
...is there a specific reason you want to create a specific type and a specific length?

Answer (score 7):

You've already accepted an answer, but since you tagged `ctypes` you might want to know how to create arrays of ctypes types:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_void_p * 1024                # NOTE: this is a TYPE
<class '__main__.c_void_p_Array_1024'>
>>> (ctypes.c_void_p * 1024)()            # This is an INSTANCE 
<__main__.c_void_p_Array_1024 object at 0x009BB5D0>
```